# my server reports WAT timezone, I've never heard of that timezone, what is it?

Tags: ubuntu

I wanted to check what timezone my server is in so I entered

```
date +'%:z %Z'
```

and got

```
+00:01 WAT
```

I've never heard of WAT timezone, I also typed

```
cat /etc/timezone
```

and got back

```
Africa/Lagos
```

My server is digitalocean droplet and is supposed to be in England, any idea why my timezone is WAT and why it's reporting to be Africa/Lagos?

Comment: Googling "WAT timezone" finds it's **W**est **A**frican **T**imezone, so `Africa/Lagos` fits. As to why somebody chose this timezone for your server: Maybe because `Africa/Lagos` is the first entry to choose from?

Comment: hi thanks for this, I did google for WAT timezone and google found nothing here is what it returned to me http://i.imgur.com/xT5pbMj.png absolutly nothing about West Africa time

Answer (score 3):

WAT is [West Africa Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Africa_Time), UTC+01:00.  Interestingly, the [Europe/London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London) timezone is *also* UTC+01:00 *when [Daylight Savings Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is in effect*.  Perhaps, then, someone provisioning that server looked at the UTC offset, and chose a matching offset, just with a different timezone.